# How to change values of dataframe cells based on following row cell value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working in Python, with Pandas DataFrames.

I have a problem where my dataframe looks like this:

```
Index    A       B    Copy_of_B
1        a       0       0
2        a       1       1
3        a       5       5
4        b       0       0
5        b       4       4
6        c       6       6
```

My expected output is:

```
Index    A       B    Copy_of_B
1        a       0       1
2        a       1       1
3        a       5       5
4        b       0       4
5        b       4       4
6        c       6       6
```

I would like to replace the 0 values in the `Copy_of_B` column with the values in the following row, but I don't want to use a for loop to iterate. 
Is there an easy solution for this?

Thanks,

Barna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make use of fact that your DataFrame has index composed of consecutive numbers.

Start from creating 2 indices:

```
ind = df[df.Copy_of_B == 0].index
ind2 = ind + 1
```

The first contains index values of rows where *Copy_of_B == 0*.
The second contains indices of subsequent rows.

Then, to "copy" data from subsequent rows to rows containing zeroes, run:

```
df.loc[ind, 'Copy_of_B'] = df.loc[ind2, 'Copy_of_B'].tolist()
```

As you can see, **without** any loop running over the whole DataFrame.

Comment: Thank you! 
This is a great solution! I think this gives an answer to another problem of mine too where I want to change the value of a different column's cell as well in the same row where 'copy_of_B' equals 0

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mask` and `bfill`:

```
df['Copy_of_B'] = df['B'].mask(df['B'].eq(0)).bfill()
```

Output:

```
   Index  A  B  Copy_of_B
0      1  a  0        1.0
1      2  a  1        1.0
2      3  a  5        5.0
3      4  b  0        4.0
4      5  b  4        4.0
5      6  c  6        6.0
```